# how to display notification on dashboard

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a requirement to display a notification bell icon in my dashboard.

basically, I would like to show the actions which need to be performed by the user should be shown as a notification.

ex: task rejected, task approved or pending for verification etc.

my application is built based on spring boot micro-services and front end we are using angular.

I have a confusion that how can i show the notification dynamically without refreshing the page and if can I leverage Kafka  for this requirement.
or if any better solution is there. please  suggest how to achieve this and what technical stack which is suitable for this requirement.

Comment: No, Kafka doesn't natively integrate with frontend libraries. You'll need some websockets layer

Answer (score 1):

You can use many different services to push notification. If you are developing on Spring boot, I suggest using [Spring Boot Starter Websocket Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-websocket). You can easily configure a simple message broker with enabling STOMP over WebSocket.

You can find a comprehensive tutorial of developing a Push Notification to all users or only to a specific user [here](https://refactorfirst.com/spring-boot-websockets-stomp-notifications)